# wait for json to be completed in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, callback, xmlhttprequest

I've read a [very similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361699/wait-for-json-call-to-be-completed-in-javascript#) but i don't use JQuery.

here's the problem : i want my json fully loaded before calling my function. I know that i must use a callback, but I dunno why my brain can't make it.

here's the "json" (truncated because it's not the subject):

```
{type: "robot", nom: "445250sup01", ville: "RENNES", departement: "35", region: "Ouest", …}
{type: "robot", nom: "445250sup02", ville: "PARIS", departement: "75", region: "Ile-de-France", …}
{type: "robot", nom: "445250sup13", ville: "ORLEANS", departement: "45", region: "Ouest", …}
```

Here's the call of my function xhr and the reading of the json :

```
var getDatas = getXHR(), // xhr in another file
    regions = {};
    dateRange = [];

getDatas.open("GET", "./db/datas.json", true);
getDatas.send();

getDatas.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (getDatas.readyState === 4 && (getDatas.status === 200 || getDatas.status === 0)) {
        var robotsList = JSON.parse(getDatas.responseText);
        getRobotsDatas(robotsList);
    }
};

function getRobotsDatas(robotList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < robotList.length - 1; i++) {...}
```

The problem is that the last object is never loaded...
Could you help me to find the right way to do it please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `robotsList` is actually an array of objects (which is not completely clear from your "json" snippet (which is not json at all, for that matter)).

You may want to take a look at the way you're cycling through the array in the `getRobotsDatas` function.

You're doing one cycle too few. That is

```
for (var i = 0; i < robotList.length - 1; i++)
```

should be either

```
for (var i = 0; i < robotList.length; i++) // removed the - 1
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i <= robotList.length - 1; i++) // changed < to <=
```

In my opinion the first one is clearer.

Comment: oh yes! you re definately right!!!!!... i thought i changed the loop from: "for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)" to  "for (var i = 0; i >= Things.length ; i++)" ! thanks Hawkeye! :D

Comment: @user2940931 if this solves your problem it would be really appreciated if you could mark the answer as correct :)